# Is there a .net 4/Visual Studio 2010 version of the Atom Publishing Template

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, atom-feed

For .net 3.5/VS2008 there is the [WCF Rest Starter Kit](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/wcf-rest) which includes Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.dll which has classes like the AtomPubServiceBase class.

Since this is Preview 2 and was released more than a year ago, I wonder if Microsoft rolled it into .net 4 as an official component or if they abandoned it?

Is there a "Atom Publishing Service Starter Kit" for .net 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up building my own solution, as there is none in .net 4 and the WCF Rest Starter Kit is abandoned.